# ListView with search function not expected behavior

Tags: android, listview, search

I've a ListView filled with the data of an ArrayAdapter and I've implemented a search function because the list is very long.

Let's say that I have this list:

0 - orange
1 - apple
2 - tomatoe
3 - alligator
4 - train
5 - turtle
6 - dog
7 - cat

Okay, now in the EditText I use to filter this list, I write a `t`. Then, the list will be:

0 - tomatoe
1 - train
2 - turtle

The problem is that I've implemented an `onItemClickListener` so that I can access to a page or another depending on the item and when I click on the first one ( 0 - tometoe ), it picks the ( 0 ) of the first element of the list without filtering (0 - orange), when I click on the second one (1 - train), it picks the (1) of the first element of the list without filtering (1 - apple) and so on...

Here's the code I'm using:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        final String[] tricks;
        
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewcustom, tricks);
        
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                showTrick(arg2, tricks[arg2], modality);
                //Log.e("itemClickListener", String.valueOf("LISTVIEWJ     " + arg2 + " - " + tricks[arg2] + " - " + modality));
            }
        });
        
        searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
         
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }
         
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
        });

        tricksLayout.addView(lv, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

So my question is: How can I manage to get it working as I want?

Comment: Do you call `notifyDataSetChanged` after `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not completely understand your question. Here is the answer what I understand from your question, if it is not what you asked make a comment I will edit my answer.

Make an ArrayList and populate it.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("orange"); //1
list.add("apple"); //2
list.add("tomatoe"); //3
list.add("alligator"); //4
list.add("train"); //5
```

On filter you get listview like this
0 - tomatoe 1 - train 2 - turtle

And now on onItemClickListener when you click on position 1

```
String temp =  here you get "train" at index 1 
//temp = "train"

int i = termsList.indexOf("train"); 
// it will give you actual position of train which is 5
```

EDITED

Also use `notifyDataSetChanged` to update list properly.

Comment: Ok, I understand and I know how to implement it but... I was looking for something that does that automatically. As a comment in my question there is Wenhui who says something about `notifyDataSetChanged`. I'll take it a look. If I've no more options, I'll check yours as the good one ;)

Comment: Add this line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`, see if it works.

Comment: @Wenhui Same problem... It is still picking the value of the not filtered list...

Comment: @Wenhui The code related with the `ListView` and the `adapter` is all on my question.

Comment: @KrLx_roller You filter the adapter, but at the line `showTrick(arg2, tricks[arg2], modality);`, where you get the item from `tricks` which you have not filtered, so instead of `tricks[arg2]`, you should use `(String)adapter.getItem(arg2)`.

Comment: OK, now it is getting the correct name but... it is still picking the `zero` at the start of the `ListView`, instead of maintaining the original position of that item on the array :/  Thank you!

Comment: Solved it. I used `String trick = adapter.getItem(arg2);` `int position = java.util.Arrays.asList(tricks).indexOf(trick);` and `showTrick(position, trick, modality);`. I do not know if this is the worst way to achieve this but... by the moment it works. Do you know if there's any other function maybe not so bad? Thank you!

Comment: @KrLx_roller I think this the only way, this is same as what I answered earlier

Comment: @SyedZahidAli Being honest it is a mix of both his and yours responses because your code without `notifyDataSetChanged` does not work... The first editing answer will be the winner :P